# Empty Character while looping

Tags: swift, string

Hey i have a string which printed gives the following: BBBKKKKJJJJJJGGG​G

If I use this code:

```
for (index,character) in vin.characters.enumerated(){
        print(character)
        vinTextFields[index].text = String(character)

    }
```

to split it into some textFields the index is out of range. This is because  the for loop inserts an empty character.

[image]
This is what the print(character) gives me back.

I really not get why this empty line appears.

Comment: You've got a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between the last two Gs. Copy and paste to the Terminal.app to see.

Comment: Yes but i don't know where it can be added

Comment: The output of `debugPrint(vin)` should show all special characters in the string.

Comment: Then you need to think more about how `vin` was created. We can't tell you that. You gave _no_ information about it. Your issue is effectively answered.

Comment: even here as html there is this character :)  `<p>Hey i have a string which printed gives the following: BBBKKKKJJJJJJGGG#8203;​G</p>`

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it, it seems there is a character that is not printable between the last two 'G'.
I think you copied and pasted it from somewhere. That's how that character made it there.
Remove the last two 'G' and type them again and you will be good to go. I tested that too.